ValueError: Sequential model 'sequential' has no defined outputs yet
i want to wrap the model with akerasClassifier and run model_prediction = model.fit i get an error that i never got before a few months ago
this is the model i built
def create_model(embed_dim = 16, hidden_unit = 16, dropout_rate = 0.2,optimizers = Adam, learning_rate = 0.001):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(input_dim = max_features, output_dim = embed_dim, input_length = X_train.shape[1]))
    model.add(LSTM(units = hidden_unit, activation = 'tanh'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(units = 3, activation = 'softmax'))
    model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = optimizers(learning_rate = learning_rate), metrics = ['accuracy'])
    print(model.summary())
    return model

and my code wrapper
model = KerasClassifier(model = create_model,
                        # Model Parameters
                        dropout_rate = 0.2,
                        embed_dim = 32,
                        hidden_unit = 16,
                        optimizers = Adam,
                        learning_rate = 0.001,
                        # Fit Parameters
                        epochs=25,
                        batch_size=128,
                        # Initiate validation data, which is 10% data from data train. It's used for evaluation model
                        validation_split = 0.1)
model_prediction = model.fit(X_train, y_train)

The following is the error I encountered:
Model: "sequential_3"
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                         ┃ Output Shape                ┃         Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ embedding_3 (Embedding)              │ ?                           │     0 (unbuilt) │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ lstm_3 (LSTM)                        │ ?                           │     0 (unbuilt) │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dropout_3 (Dropout)                  │ ?                           │     0 (unbuilt) │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense_3 (Dense)                      │ ?                           │     0 (unbuilt) │
└──────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┘
 Total params: 0 (0.00 B)
 Trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)
 Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)
None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-6053ea388551> in <cell line: 13>()
     11 
     12 
---> 13 model_prediction = model.fit(X_train, y_train)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, **kwargs)
   1499             sample_weight = 1 if sample_weight is None else sample_weight
   1500             sample_weight *= compute_sample_weight(class_weight=self.class_weight, y=y)
-> 1501         super().fit(X=X, y=y, sample_weight=sample_weight, **kwargs)
   1502         return self
   1503 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, **kwargs)
    768         kwargs["initial_epoch"] = kwargs.get("initial_epoch", 0)
    769 
--> 770         self._fit(
    771             X=X,
    772             y=y,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py in _fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, warm_start, epochs, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
    934         X = self.feature_encoder_.transform(X)
    935 
--> 936         self._check_model_compatibility(y)
    937 
    938         self._fit_keras_model(

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py in _check_model_compatibility(self, y)
    557             # we recognize the attribute but do not force it to be
    558             # generated
--> 559             if self.n_outputs_expected_ != len(self.model_.outputs):
    560                 raise ValueError(
    561                     "Detected a Keras model input of size"

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/models/sequential.py in outputs(self)
    281         if self._functional:
    282             return self._functional.outputs
--> 283         raise ValueError(
    284             f"Sequential model '{self.name}' has no defined outputs yet."
    285         )

ValueError: Sequential model 'sequential' has no defined outputs yet.


I have tried upgrading the Keras library and tried rebuilding the model but I still get the error.
Is there a step added to cause this error to occur? what should i do to fix this?

You need the specify the number of output expected to have by the Keras model as specified in the documentation
n_outputs_expected_int : The number of outputs the Keras Model is expected to have, as determined by target_transformer_.

please tell me how i do that

model.n_outputs_expected_ = 3
i add this and still error, pls help

Me too, I opened another question, mine is related to gridsearch parameter optimization.
